# Concrete base for summer house

Tags: concrete

I need to make a concrete base for a summer house/office. How much sand and cement will I need for 3.5m x 3.5m area to a depth of 10cms?

Comment: Stealing a comment from somewhere else… call your local concrete plant and ask if they’d be willing to put an extra yard-and-a-half (or a little over 1 cubic meter) on a nearby job. Depending on geography, you might also have access to small batch mobile mixers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [concrete calculator](https://www.calculator.net/concrete-calculator.html)  The measurements can be changed to metric.

You did not mention if you were having footings or it was just a slab. Using the calculator will answer your question based on your input.